# Namespace auto-detected -- what's behind the scene?

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

Does C++ overload all same-name functions from different namespaces, and auto-detect which one to use for you? For example, the following piece of code calls a function **Concat** without specifying its namespace:

```
namespace nsA {
    class A { public: A(std::string s): val(s) {}; std::string val; };
    void Concat(A &aa, A &a1, A &a2) { aa = A(a1.val + a2.val); }
};

namespace nsB {
    class B: public nsA::A { public: B(std::string s): nsA::A(s + " ") {} };
    void Concat(B &bb, B &b1, B &b2) { bb = B(b1.val + b2.val + "!"); }
};

void main() {
    nsA::A a1("Hello"), a2("World"), aa("");
    nsB::B b1("Hello"), b2("World"), bb("");
    Concat(aa, a1, a2); Concat(bb, b1, b2); // namespace not specified
    std::cout << aa.val << std::endl << bb.val << std::endl;
}
```

And the outputs of main function:

```
HelloWorld
Hello World !
```

Without **using namespace**, without calling function with **namespace::function**, why does it work? Even though it works, are there better practices to overload functions from different class and namespace?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Why should we guess how `nsA::A` looks like, if we want to try your example on our own?

Comment: Look at [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Comment: @ceylon Here is used the so-called ADL (argument dependent lookup),

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's funny that you tagged your own question with the answer you are looking for! **Argument Dependent Lookup**